# Can an integral always be written as an infinite sum?

Tags: integration, surfaces, riemann-integration

I'm currently reading about computing the surface area of revolution and encountered the following:

The author first approximates the area by partitioning the interval into a finite number of subintervals to obtain
$$
A \approx \sum_{i = 1}^{n} 2\pi f(x_i^{*})\sqrt{1 + \left[ f'(x_i^{*}) \right]^2 } \ \Delta x
\quad (\Delta x = x_{i}-x_{i-1},\ x_i^{*} \in [x_{i-1}, x_i])
$$
and then proceeds by making the subintervals "smaller and smaller" to obtain

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2 \pi f\left(x_{i}^{*}\right) \sqrt{1+\left[f^{\prime}\left(x_{i}^{*}\right)\right]^{2}} \Delta x=\int_{a}^{b} 2 \pi f(x) \sqrt{1+\left[f^{\prime}(x)\right]^{2}} d x
.$$
Intuitively, I understand the last step, but isn't the Riemann integral defined in terms of finite partitions, so the limit isn't really valid here? (Wouldn't one have to use the mean value theorem in order to make this rigorous?)

Comment: If the integral exists, then the Riemann sums (which are indeed finite sums) can be made arbitrarily close to the integral by taking fine enough partitions. So while this isn't very rigorous (the author doesn't even define what $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ means in this context), I think it's morally legitimate as long as the integral is known to exist.

Comment: You might want to read about Riemann sums, in this context the above becomes more rigorous. As Bungo said, you can make the error between the Riemann sum and the integral arbitrary small, leading to the limit expression (however, one has to prove this first).

Comment: One can actually also define the Riemann integral this way, as the limit value over all partitions as the mesh size goes to 0.

Comment: Consider that the notion of integral that you are familiar with has been in metric spaces or when the notion of area has been additive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the theorem s.t. it becomes rigorous.

Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, if $P=\left\{t_{0}, \ldots, t_{n}\right\}$ is any partition of $[a, b]$ with all lengths $t_{i}-t_{i-1}<\delta$, then
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right)\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right)-\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x\right|<\varepsilon
$$
for any Riemann sum formed by choosing $x_{i} \in\left[t_{i-1}, t_{i}\right]$. Notice that a Riemann sum is just any sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right)\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right)
$$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \inf\left\{f\left(x_{i}\right)\mid x_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\right\}\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right)}_{\large:= L(f, P)}  &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right)\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right) \\[10pt]
&\leq\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sup\left\{f\left(x_{i}\right)\mid x_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\right\}\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right)}_{\large := U(f, P)} .
\end{align*}
Here, $L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)$ denote the lower and upper sums and a Riemann sum is just any sum of the above form that lies between the lower and upper sum.
Since the Riemann sum and the integral both lie between $L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)$, this amounts to showing that for any given $\varepsilon$ we can make $U(f, P)-L(f, P)<\varepsilon$ by choosing a $\delta$ such that $U(f, P)-L(f, P)<\varepsilon$ for any partition with all lengths $t_{i}-t_{i-1}<\delta$
The definition of $f$ being integrable on $[a, b]$ includes the condition that $|f| \leq$ $M$ for some $M .$ First choose some particular partition $P^{*}=\left\{u_{0}, \ldots \ldots u_{K}\right\}$ for which
$$
U\left(f, P^{*}\right)-L\left(f, P^{*}\right)<\varepsilon / 2
$$
and then choose a $\delta$ such that
$$
\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{4 M K}
$$
For any partition $P$ with all $t_{i}-t_{i-1}<\delta$, we can break the sum
$$
U(f, P)-L(f, P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(M_{i}-m_{i}\right)\left(t_{i}-t_{i-1}\right)
$$
into two sums. The first involves those $i$ for which the interval $\left[t_{i-1}, t_{i}\right]$ is completely contained within one of the intervals $\left[u_{j-1}, u_{j}\right] .$ This sum is clearly $\leq$ $U\left(f, P^{*}\right)-L\left(f, P^{*}\right)<\varepsilon / 2$. For all other $i$ we will have $t_{i-1}<u_{j}<t_{i}$ for some $j=1, \ldots, K-1$, so there are at most $K-1$ of them. Consequently, the sum for these terms is $<(K-1) \cdot 2 M \cdot \delta<\varepsilon / 2.$

---

*Spivak, Michael - Calculus 4th edition*